# how to merge from a different fork in github

Tags: git, github

Say there is a project "A" in github. I forked off Project B (A->B) that I'm working on.
Someone created project C from A (A->C). There are some pull requests made from C to A, but it has not been merged yet.

How can I merge C's changes to mine (B) ? 
I do have C's commit hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either ask the owner of `C` to send you a pull request, or easier yet, you can add his repository as remote, fetch his branches and merge all you want.

In short, for example:

```
$ git remote add C_repo path/to/C/repo
$ git fetch C_repo
$ git merge C_repo/master
```

A [Github tutorial](https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork) is available also.